# lightning-tree with drag and drop feature

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC component with a lightning-tree for role hierarchy. I need to implement a drag and drop function for the items to reorder them and save the new hierarchy.

This is the tree:

```
<lightning-tree items={items} onselect={handleSelectAssign}></lightning-tree>
```

How it looks:

[image]

Is it possible to drag and drop the items?

Best regards,
Renato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be possible with Salesforce's `lightning-data-tree`. We can't "see" the internal structure of components, either our own or those in another namespace. The shadow root for each component acts as a membrane that restricts access to the internal structure. The best you can do here is to have the user select a node, click a button, then select the other node.

Fortunately, you can swap out your current code and use the tree and treeItem components found in the [base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc) library or by grabbing the source code from the [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) npm module. This will mean, however, that you'll have to maintain your own separate copy of the tree and treeItem components.